DevOps - Import-AzApiManagementApi for a protected app service
I have a backend API (app service) with a swagger definition that I would like to import to a API Management instance in my release pipeline. The app service is protected using EasyAuth (Entra ID). I'm using Import-AzApiManagementApi to import the swagger definition:
...
$VersionSet = New-AzApiManagementApiVersionSet -Context $ApiMgmtContext -Name "Project Service API" -Description "Project Service API." -Scheme Header -HeaderName "api-version"

# v1
Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $apiMgmtContext -SpecificationFormat "OpenApi" -SpecificationUrl $(apim_SpecificationUrl) -Path $api.Path -ApiId $api.ApiId -ServiceUrl $(api_ServiceUrl) -ApiVersionSetId $VersionSet.ApiVersionSetId
...

However, I receive 401 error because DevOps (or the service principal) did not provide an access token. Is there a way to do this?

